# she must be somebody just wonderful to come home to. (meaning )

Tags: meaning

> She must be somebody just wonderful to come home to. (meaning )

Just wonder what this means and think of the structure as "~wonderful for me to come home"

Also what's the last "to" ? Means 'come home to somebody'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can imagine this as a sarcastic response to someone complaining about their wife:

> My wife won't stop nagging me the minute I come through the door.
>
> She must be someone just wonderful to come home to.

ie, it must be "just wonderful" to come home to someone like that.